# Combining like Entries and sorting the top three

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

|  | Monthly | Quarter | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| David | 5 | 7 | 24 |
| Tim | 1 | 6 | 12 |
| David | 2 | 3 | 9 |
| Ed | 4 | 6 | 7 |
| David | 3 | 6 | 12 |
| Ed | 0 | 10 | 18 |

What I need is a function that will combine & Sum all of the Monthly entries for David.  So that there is one line entry for David that give his combined Monthly / Quarterly / Yearly, in the next three columns respectively.

I will also do this with other "like names" to help consolidate multiple entries

If each of the columns has to be dealt with separately that is fine

Excellent code !
Once I Consolidate.  I next have extract the Top 3 Names and Monthly Totals (From all 100 entries).... and the top 3 Names and Totals for Quarterly...  And Likewise for Yearly. In a some cases the Highest totals may be a different set of persons, for Month, Quarter, And Year

But I figured that this would be a 3 step process.  Right now I am trying to figure how to change the target Column for A to C in your code, and how to control which column the output is displayed in.

I have figured the output part of the code.  But I am not seeing where you targeted the A Column and how I can shift that to Col C

---

---

Irregularities with the summing.  Here's an actual Example

Jim Mo=31  Q=81  Y=81

Jim Mo=0   Q=12  Y=12

The sum Should Be:
Jim Mo=31  Q=93   Y=93

Code is returning
Jim Mo=81  Q=43   Y=93

---

---

@cooper amazing code.   The edit is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with QUERY:

```
=QUERY(A:D,"SELECT A, SUM(B), SUM(C), SUM(D) group by A",1)
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

If you want to have the three top of each column, you can modify in each case adding an "order by" clause and "limit 3":

For example, for the Monthly:

```
=QUERY(A:D,"SELECT A, SUM(B), SUM(C), SUM(D) Where A is not null group by A order by SUM(B) desc limit 3",1)
```

Just changing SUM(B) in order by for each case, you can have these three results:

[image]

Comment: I cant get the the query to work.  I will retry

Comment: Retry it to se if it's your expected result. I changed some data to see the different sortings

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [h,...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const [m,q,y] = ["M","Q","Y"];//If your headers are different than mine.  Change them here
  let obj = {pA:[]};
  let idx = {};
  h.forEach((h,i) => {idx[h] = i;});
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
      obj[r[0]] = {"Q":r[idx[m]],"M":r[idx[q]],"Y":r[idx[y]]};
      obj.pA.push(r[0]); 
    } else {
      obj[r[0]].Q += r[idx[q]];
      obj[r[0]].M += r[idx[m]];
      obj[r[0]].Y += r[idx[y]];
    }
  });
  let o = obj.pA.map(p => [p,obj[p].M,obj[p].Q,obj[p].Y] );
  o.unshift(['',m,q,y]);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
  sh.getRange(1,sh.getLastColumn() + 2, o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Data and Output Tables:

|  | M | Q | Y |  |  | M | Q | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| David | 5 | 7 | 24 |  | David | 10 | 16 | 45 |
| Tim | 1 | 6 | 12 |  | Tim | 1 | 6 | 12 |
| David | 2 | 3 | 9 |  | Ed | 4 | 16 | 25 |
| Ed | 4 | 6 | 7 |  |  |  |  |  |
| David | 3 | 6 | 12 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Ed | 0 | 10 | 18 |  |  |  |  |  |

```
Execution log
8:49:00 PM  Notice  Execution started
8:48:57 PM  Info    [["","M","Q","Y"],["David","14","32","70"],["Tim",1,6,12],["Ed","","",""]]
8:49:02 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

A possible way to add additional sorted values:

Code:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const ovs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  ovs.unshift(["Original Data", "", "", ""]);
  const [h, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const [m, q, y] = ["M", "Q", "Y"];//If your headers are different than mine.  Change them here
  let obj = { pA: [] };
  let idx = {};
  h.forEach((h, i) => { idx[h.trim()] = i; });
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
      obj[r[0]] = { "Q": Number(r[idx[q]]), "M": Number(r[idx[m]]), "Y": Number(r[idx[y]]) };
      obj.pA.push(r[0]);
    } else {
      obj[r[0]].Q += Number(r[idx[q]]);
      obj[r[0]].M += Number(r[idx[m]]);
      obj[r[0]].Y += Number(r[idx[y]]);
    }
  });
  let o = obj.pA.map(p => [p, obj[p].M, obj[p].Q, obj[p].Y]);
  let osm = obj.pA.map(p => [p, obj[p].M]).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
  osm.unshift(["Name", "Sum"])
  osm.unshift(["Sorted Descending Monthly", ""]);
  let osq = obj.pA.map(p => [p, obj[p].Q]).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
  osq.unshift(["Name", "Sum"])
  osq.unshift(["Sorted Descending Quarterly", ""]);
  let osy = obj.pA.map(p => [p, obj[p].Y]).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
  osy.unshift(["Name", "Sum"])
  osy.unshift(["Sorted Descending Yearly", ""]);
  o.unshift(['', m, q, y]);
  o.unshift(['Sums', "", "", ""])
  osh.clearContents();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  osh.getRange(1, 1, ovs.length, ovs[0].length).setValues(ovs);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  osh.getRange(1, osh.getLastColumn() + 2, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  osh.getRange(1, osh.getLastColumn() + 2, osm.length, osm[0].length).setValues(osm);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  osh.getRange(1, osh.getLastColumn() + 2, osq.length, osq[0].length).setValues(osq);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  osh.getRange(1, osh.getLastColumn() + 2, osy.length, osy[0].length).setValues(osy);
  osh.getRange(1, 1, 2, osh.getLastColumn()).setFontWeight("bold");
}
```

Original Data:

Data Sheet:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | M | Q | Y |
| 2 | Name1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Name2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | Name3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | Name1 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 6 | Name2 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 7 | Name3 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 8 | Name1 | 7 | 7 | 7 |
| 9 | Name2 | 8 | 8 | 8 |
| 10 | Name3 | 9 | 9 | 9 |

Output Sheet:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Original Data |  |  |  |  | Sums |  |  |  |  | Sorted Descending Monthly |  |  | Sorted Descending Quarterly |  |  | Sorted Descending Yearly |  |
| 2 |  | M | Q | Y |  |  | M | Q | Y |  | Name | Sum |  | Name | Sum |  | Name | Sum |
| 3 | Name1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  | Name1 | 12 | 12 | 12 |  | Name3 | 18 |  | Name3 | 18 |  | Name3 | 18 |
| 4 | Name2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |  | Name2 | 15 | 15 | 15 |  | Name2 | 15 |  | Name2 | 15 |  | Name2 | 15 |
| 5 | Name3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |  | Name3 | 18 | 18 | 18 |  | Name1 | 12 |  | Name1 | 12 |  | Name1 | 12 |
| 6 | Name1 | 4 | 4 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | Name2 | 5 | 5 | 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | Name3 | 6 | 6 | 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | Name1 | 7 | 7 | 7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10 | Name2 | 8 | 8 | 8 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 11 | Name3 | 9 | 9 | 9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: You have not explained how you wish to sort or what the top 3 means.

Comment: Original message has been edited... hopefully it clarifies some

Comment: I took a stab at providing the additional output.  Hope the additional code and layout helps.

Comment: I have some irregularities with totals

Comment: Here is Irregularity with the summing. 

Jim Mo=31 Q=81 Y=81

Jim Mo=0 Q=12 Y=12

The sum Should Be: Jim Mo=31 Q=93 Y=93

Code is returning Jim Mo=81 Q=43 Y=93

Comment: Amazing Code Cooper!  Thanks So Much